# SSL certificate fields and personal address

Tags: ssl-certificate, privacy

Is it possible to get the address of the business that a SSL certificate is registered to?

I know you can get the City and State directly from the certificate.

I ask because I'm thinking about getting an SSL certificate, but I only have my home address to use.

Comment: Purchasing an SSL certificate isn't limited to business entities. Anyone with the means to purchase one (whether it be a business or an individual) can purchase one, so I'm confused as to why your home address is relevant in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A basic SSL provides an encrypted connection only. I has no actual identity information. Network Solutions sells these as "Express" certificates. Most SSL provides have an equivalent. 
The name and address provided when purchasing are for billing purposes.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it has *no* identity information. It certainly contains city and state as well as organization.

Comment: The express certs I have purchased DO NOT show city/state

Comment: Can you provide a link to a site that has one installed?

Comment: www.paydaytree.com

Comment: Interesting to learn. Have an upvote. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about SSL certs for business entities without at least locality in them (yes, they are technically valid: Really all you *need* is the CN and a trust chain, and yes it's easy to just put in the "right" locality in a faked cert, but still - bleh...)

Comment: We use them to provide a secure connection between the browser and our server. NOT as a form of system identity.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a field that's required for the cert, and therefor is not included in the cert. Some are issued with City, State, and Organization, but address is never a requirement.

Any address info collected by a vendor for a standard SSL certificate should strictly be for billing and hopefully won't be made public. It certainly won't be included in the details of your cert.